# jQuery width from CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

Sorry I made mistake. Not in PHP, in jQuery, sure.

I have a fixed form width in my jQuery. I need to do the width based on css @media screen. How can I change it in my script?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var FormWidth = $('.button').attr('data-formwidth');
    if(!FormWidth) {
        FormWidth = '400px';
    }
```

Comment: You can use PHP to conditionally set additional classes to the element (large, wide, etc) and target the element with those classes and set spesific widths in css.

Comment: @JimL, thanks. I made  mistake, now changed php to jquery

Answer (score 1):

According to me you can getting the width of the form and when you get the width you can apply css.

Here is how you can get the width of the form using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width = $('form').width();
  if (width == 400) {
     // Do something
  }
});

// Also you use $(window).resize(); function for getting width of a windows 
//  when resizing the window
```

Comment: Above code will explain for getting the width of the form and when you get the width you can apply css

Comment: @Mohd Amir, thank you. As result I used  if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)').matches) { .... it's ok. Everything works great

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work four you

```
<form style="width:<?php (isset(FormWidth)?FormWidth:500 ?>px"/>
```

second part would be default width of form

edited

for jquery you can use

```
window.innerWidth
```

to detect width of browser , then you can decide which class you want to add to your form